# how to invoke an operation with the data we get after processing

Tags: workflow, tivoli, tivoli-identity-manager

Hello guys I'm looking for creating an work flow where it will do some processing and will fetch some persons. I need to enforce each person by invoking an extension which takes a person entity as in put. 
Any suggestions or pointers will be deeply appreciated.

Comment: Could you show us what you have tried?

Answer (score 1):

I going to to assume you want to use an ITIM operation to do this, and you are not going to use an operation tied to an activity (e.g. person/account modify, restore, suspend, add, delete, etc.).

So for example, if you want to create an operation that fetches all users where their `department=sales` and you want to make a change to those persons (e.g. change all their phone numbers to be 800-555-1212) then you could use a lifecycle rule coupled with an operation.

First create an operation.  I would suggest creating the operation at the entity type level of Person unless you need to specifically only allow this operation to work on one person type.  Once you get into the operation diagram java applet, click the Properties button and change the `operation type` to `Non Static`.

Now, do your coding and flow in the operation.  Your person will be coming in as the relevant data object Entity.  So make your changes in a script node, then send it through a modify person extension, and finally a policy enforcement extension.  I recommend the policy enforcement extension because if you are using provisioning policies then you want any accounts to be updated when you update the extension.

Save your operation, and create a lifecycle at the same level (either at the global Person at the entity level of a specific Person type).  Set the operation for the lifecycle to the same operation you just created.  On the event page, set your filter to be what you are wanting the operation to apply to (e.g. `(department=sales)`).  You can set a schedule on the lifecycle to automate it, or you can simply save it and run the lifecycle manually by selecting it and clicking the Run button.

Check within IBM's InfoCenter pages for more information on all the workflow extensions that are available out of the box, as well as all of the javascript functions that are available.